# Apply Style When Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a small script consisting of the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
```

And some HTML:

```
<a href="#admin" onclick="toggle_visibility('test').style.display='block';">Test Me</a>   
<br/>

<div id="test" style="display:none;">
    Hello there
</div>
```

The code makes it so that when the Test Me link is clicked the  becomes visible, I am curious about how to make it so that when clicked the Test Me link the text colour would change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well.
First the onclick attr is wrong, you see. The function is calling `toggle_...`, then it makes the rest.
The js-script

```
function toggle_visibility(id,$this) {
var e = document.getElementById(id);
if(e.style.display == 'block')
{
  $this.style.color = '';
  e.style.display = 'none';
}
else
{
   $this.style.color = 'gold';
   e.style.display = 'block';
}
}
```

and the html-code

```
<a href="#admin" onclick="toggle_visibility('test',this)">Test Me</a><br/>
<div id="test" style="display:none;">
   Hello there
```

Edit, I also added $this to also now the element that was clicked.

Comment: Thanks for the post, but you have not really answered the question - the code seems to be working for me. I just wanted to know how to make the 'Test Me' text change colour when it is selected and the <div id="test"> is visible?

Answer (score 0):

```
onclick="javascript: jQuery('#test').css('color', 'red'); return false;"
```

Comment: That does not seem to work, even when I remove the other necessary code.

Comment: No, it is not working because @lynks is referring to a javascript lib.

Comment: remove the display: none from your div, otherwise it will never appear (we are overriding the code that makes it appear with code that changes its colour). and override the onclick you already have, with the one i provide.

Comment: the question was tagged with jquery, so i assumed it would be ok to use.

Comment: The jQuery script is actually included in the html document, so it should've be working in theory then...